# Sql Query to retrieve data using table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need query to get the count of participants in each level.

Note: participant who is in level 4 should not be in other levels ex: Level 3,2,1. I.e. I'm only interested in the highest level of each participant.

**Table** :

```
  +----+-------+----------+
  | ID | Level |  Date    |
  +----+-------+----------+
  | 38 | 1     |  06 -05  |
  | 38 | 2     |  08 -05  |
  | 38 | 3     |  12 -05  |
  | 38 | 4     |  13 -05  |
  | 39 | 1     |  13 -05  |
  | 39 | 2     |  13 -05  |
  | 40 | 1     |  12 -05  |
  +----+-------+----------+
```

Needed Output:

```
  +-------+-------+ 
  | Count | Level | 
  +-------+-------+ 
  | 1     | 1     |
  | 1     | 2     |
  | 0     | 3     |
  | 1     | 4     |
  +-------+-------+
```

Comment: how for level 3 you have 0 count with the given data ?

Comment: State Your expectaion clearly....

Comment: participant ID  38 already existed in level 4 so that we consider only highest level

Comment: No participants is having highest level with 3

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(t2.Id) as count,t1.Level as level
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Id,MAX(Level) as Level
FROM table1
GROUP BY Id ) t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id and t1.Level=t2.Level
GROUP BY t1.Level
```

You can test it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/053447/10)

Comment: What are the efficiency constraints in this query?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the bottleneck, performance-wise is the join with the result set on the 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
Select Count(*), Level FROM table_name GROUP BY Level
```

Comment: In this query we count participant id 38 in all levels but we need count only in level 4

Answer (score 0):

the expected result is to know how many people have a level as max level, grouping by level.

```
SELECT count(id) as count, level
FROM
(
  SELECT id, max(level) as level
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY id
) t1
GROUP BY level;
```

Comment: This won't show the row where level is 3 and count is 0.